# Writing csv file in Python: unwanted commas appear

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to extract a list of dictionary values into a file with the following code:

```
import csv

def function(file, output, deli = ','):

    dictionary = dict()
    with open(file, 'r') as source, open(output, 'w') as outp:
        data = csv.reader(source)
        line0 = next(data)
        i = 0
        for element in line0:
            dictionary[i] = element
            i += 1
        my_writer = csv.writer(outp)
        for element in dictionary.values():
            print(element)
            my_writer.writerow(element)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sys import argv
    if len(argv) == 2:
        function(argv[1])
    elif len(argv) == 3:
        function(argv[1], argv[2])
    elif len(argv) == 4:
        function(argv[1], argv[2], argv[3])

    print("ok")
```

To run this code on the shell, I use the command:
python function.py input output

However, trying on a csv file like:
alpha, beta, gamma, delta

I get the following result:

```
a,l,p,h,a

 ,b,e,t,a

 ,g,a,m,m,a

 ,d,e,l,t,a
```

I tried to change the delimiter to ' ' and I got the same result with spaces instead of commas.

Am I missing something?

Comment: How is the output you are getting different from the output you are expecting?

Comment: I was expecting to have:
alpha,
beta,
gamma,
delta

Comment: @bigTree what are you attempting to do with the `dict` ?

Comment: @JonClements I created the dictionary to have an easy way to access the elements in line0 (in fact, the original csv file has one element per column and I want to retrieve the column number of each element)

Comment: A dictionary with keys as `0,1,2,3,` can _probably_ be replaced by a list

Comment: would that be computationally more efficient?

Comment: It would be easier to code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the lines

```
for element in dictionary.values():
    print(element)
    my_writer.writerow(element)
```

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#writer-objects) argument to `writerow` should be a list of objects. In your case the argument is a string (which is iterable).
So what you are actually doing is `my_writer.writerow("alpha")` which is written as `a,l,p,h,a`.

You should simply do

```
my_writer.writerow(element.values())
```

Also, you are getting leading commas beacuse your CSV string is `alpha, beta, gamma`. So when the split happens the elements are `['aplha',' beta',' gamma',]`. You could use `strip()` to remove them

Comment: This is it! I tried the code with a list as input to writerows and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping over the characters in the line instead of the actual elements

```
with open(file_, 'r') as source, open(output, 'w') as outp:
    data = csv.reader(source, delimiter=deli)
    #line0 = next(data)
    i = 0
    for element in data:
        dictionary[i] = element
        i += 1
```

also it's considered to be good practice to not override the built-ins in this case you are overriding `file`, [instead PEP 008 recommends that you add an underscore to the end of you variable name](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles).

Comment: I actually retrieved the first line of the file with next(data) (The csv file I am working on is huge and I just need the first line)